# Grouping Sum of Items by Month

Tags: sql, ssms-2017

I have a view for all invoiced transactions with fields item, qty_sold, and invoice_date. It displays like this.

| Item | QTY_Shipped | Invoice_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 | 02/01/2021 |
| Apple | 4 | 10/25/2021 |
| Pear | 15 | 05/10/2021 |
| Strawberry | 10 | 04/10/2021 |
| Nectarine | 405 | 08/01/2021 |
| Strawberry | 5 | 10/01/2021 |
| Apple | 5 | 02/25/2021 |

And, I am trying to sum all items according to the month/period like the table below.

| Year | Period | Item | Sum_QTY_Shipped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2 | Apple | 7 |
| 2021 | 4 | Strawberry | 10 |
| 2021 | 5 | Pear | 15 |
| 2021 | 8 | Nectarine | 405 |
| 2021 | 10 | Strawberry | 5 |
| 2021 | 10 | Apple | 4 |

I am using the below query and have tried using the SUM function but keep getting a 'Column 'v_sales_by_order_date.Invoice_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' message.

```
    select YEAR(Invoice_Date) as 'Year', MONTH(Invoice_Date) as 'Period', Item, Qty
    from v_sales_by_order_date
    order by Invoice_Date
```

Comment: I don't see any `sum` function in your query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` as follows

```sql
SELECT
  YEAR(Invoice_Date) as 'Year',
  MONTH(Invoice_Date) as 'Period',
  Item,
  SUM(QTY) total
FROM
  v_sales_by_order_date
GROUP BY
  YEAR(Invoice_Date),
  MONTH(Invoice_Date),
  Item
ORDER BY
  YEAR(Invoice_Date),
  MONTH(Invoice_Date),
  Item;
```